# Logical operators and branch prediction failure

Tags: c++, performance, compiler-optimization, short-circuiting, branch-prediction

Consider the following loops:

```
while((expressionA) & (expressionB)){
    // do something
}
```

```
while((expressionA) && (expressionB)){
    // do something
}
```

where `expressionA` and `expressionB` are expressions of type `bool` and `expressionB` has no side-effects. Under these conditions, the two cases are *as-if*-equivalent (right?).

A (hypothetical) compiler that naively takes its cue from the source code would put a branch in the `&&` version and we would end up [paying for branch prediction failures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/827280).

With a modern compiler (such as current GCC), can there ever be any conditions under which the `&` version gives a substantial performance gain over of the `&&` version?

---

My guess is no, because:

- If `expressionB` is sufficiently cheap, the compiler will recognize this and avoid creating the short-circuiting branch.
- If `expressionB` is sufficiently expensive, the compiler will create the short-circuit because:

  - if probability of `expressionA` is not close to 1.0, we get a substantial average performance gain from short-circuiting.
  - if probability of `expressionA` is close to 1.0, we won't pay much because branch prediction will tend to succeed.

Comment: If expressionA has side-effects , they cannot be avoided

Comment: AFAIK there's no way of telling the optimizer which cases are the most likely, which makes it difficult for cases like `if ( a && b && c && d && e )` where there are no side-effects  but computationally expensive. Theoretically the C standard would allow the tests to be done in any order so even if you put the most expensive first, the optimizer might not honour that.

Comment: What I'm finding just playing around in GCC 5.2 on some simplistic tests is that `operator&` can actually cause a slight difference in register allocation, but identical to `operator&&` in terms of branching (at least with operands that evaluate to `bool`). One thing, as M.M. alluded to, is that a compiler can't truly figure out what is "cheap" here, since the probability/predictability of a coin flip expression is often going to be based around inputs only provided at runtime. It goes beyond the basic evaluation. What I'm seeing is short-circuiting being applied for *both* operators here.

Comment: @M.M Could you please explain why you brought up the side-effects of `expressionA`?

Comment: @Ike Thanks. By "cheap expression" I just mean one that can be evaluated quickly, so in that sense the compiler *can* figure out what is cheap. Probability matters of course, but as a separate factor. Take the case where `expressionB` is just a `bool` variable whose value is unknown at compile-time but is already evaluated (at this point in run-time) because its value was already needed elsewhere in the code. That value is available "cheaply" and making the short-circuit in that case (for any of the two operators) would just seem wasteful, especially because branch prediction may fail.

Comment: gcc usually makes a separate branch instruction for each piece of a short-circuit-evaluated conditional.  If (A&B) predicts well, but neither A nor B alone predict well, I think you could see a benefit to using `A&B` over `A&&B`.  Turning a comparison into a value that can actually be bitwise-ANDed with something else usually isn't cheap, though.  It's a lot easier in the `||` vs. `|` case, because usually you can just compute things an `OR` them together.   e.g. `2 | 1` is true, but `2 & 1` is false.

Comment: @tennenrishin Understood what you meant there by cheap/expensive as relating to the cost of evaluation. What I was seeing fooling around in GCC was that, in cases where both operators produce logically equivalent results, the optimizer was still short-circuiting them (yielding two branch instructions instead of an `and` instruction + branch). My guess for why it does that is that it still can't assume anything on the part of the predictability of an expression to be able to easily deduce that an `and` instruction would not degrade branch predictability.